# Передвижение кнопки в Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Здравствуйте!Я делаю некоторую "игру", по заполнению магического квадрата 3 на 3.Необходимо сделать : слева -  пустое поля 3 на 3, справа набор цифр от 1 до 9 которые можно перетягивать,расставляя по полю,а также,чтобы после попадания на поле, цифру нельзя было взять повторно(т.е. цифры повторяться не должны). Есть идея: сделать 9 пустых кнопок как поле,и 9 с лейбалами под соответствующими цифрами.И при перетягивании кнопка-поле будет получать соответствующий лейбл,а кнопка-цифра становиться пустой.Возможно ли это?Либо лучше организовать это как картинки и перетягивать уже картинки.Подскажите пожалуйста,как осуществить это перетягивание(код) и получить значение с перетягиваемого элемента( в массив например,нужно будет проверять сумму элементов по строкам,столбцам,диагоналям).Заранее спасибо.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавляем пространства имен:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Код класса:

```
class MyButton : Button
{
    //точка перемещения
    Point DownPoint;
    //нажата ли кнопка мыши
    bool IsDragMode;

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs mevent)
    {
        DownPoint = mevent.Location;
        IsDragMode = true;
        base.OnMouseDown(mevent);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
    {
        IsDragMode = false;
        base.OnMouseUp(mevent);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs mevent)
    {
        //если кнопка мыши нажата
        if (IsDragMode)
        {
            Point p = mevent.Location;
            //вычисляем разницу в координатах между положением курсора и "нулевой" точкой кнопки
            Point dp = new Point(p.X - DownPoint.X, p.Y - DownPoint.Y);
            Location = new Point(Location.X + dp.X, Location.Y + dp.Y);
        }
        base.OnMouseMove(mevent);
    }
}
```

Теперь добавим созданную кнопку на нашу форму и протестируем наше приложение:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MyButton btn = new MyButton();
    btn.Name = "btn";
    btn.SetBounds(10, 10, 130, 23);
    btn.Text = "My Button";
    this.Controls.Add(btn);
}
```

Взято из этой [статьи](http://csharpcoding.org/peremeshhenie-knopki-po-forme/). Может пригодиться.